# How to do WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(*) ...) = 0 OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ...))?

Tags: sql, join, exists

For example, I have a table `Person` having an ID for each entry and I have a table `PersonEvent` which records the `personID` of each person at an event.

If `PersonEvent` contains no rows for the event, everyone in the `Person` table attended.  However if there are entries in the `PersonEvent` table, only those people attended the event.

I want to do a query such as:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Person p 
WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM PersonEvent pe 
        WHERE pe.personID = p.ID 
        AND pe.eventID = '290') = 0 
      OR EXISTS 
        (SELECT * 
         FROM PersonEvent pe 
         WHERE pe.personID = p.ID 
         AND pe.eventID = '290'))
```

How do I do this?

Comment: what is the database server? It matters for query syntax

Comment: @sehe Thanks - SQL 2008, although I'm sure I'd be able to convert syntax, was just struggling a bit with the logic. RichardTheKiwi has it sorted!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM Person p
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( -- not a single person for the event
       SELECT *
         FROM PersonEvent
        WHERE eventID = '290')
    OR EXISTS ( -- the person for the event
       SELECT *
         FROM PersonEvent pe
        WHERE pe.personID = p.ID AND pe.eventID = '290')
```